# Image loading and stream/file dependency

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, bitmap

Right now I have an application that loads a bunch of thumbnail images into PictureBox controls.  Sometimes over a hundred at a time.  The images are created using Image.FromStream(MemoryStream), and the memory stream represents each JPG file.

Currently, as soon as I am calling Image.FromStream, I assign the reference to the picture box, then immediately after I Flush() and Dispose() the stream.

According to documentation, I should not release the stream until I'm done with the image.  However, I have not had any errors doing this.  My PictureBox controls can repaint themselves all day long with the thumbnail images even after the memory streams have long been disposed.

However, if I try to access these images in any way, such as calling the Save function, it throws an error.

- If a Bitmap has a dependency on a memory stream or file stream, will it dispose of the source when you dispose of it?  Or is this only when it creates the stream itself using Bitmap.FromFile?
- Is disposing of the MemoryStream immediately like I am doing considered OK?  The PictureBox must be caching the image in some way.  I've never had an error because I don't need to touch the image once it has been set.

I also notice that it takes my PictureBoxes a long time to paint on their parent control.  I am not sure if this is because I have too many controls, or because there is a delay the first time an image is painted in a PictureBox.

I know that when you create a new Bitmap with a file parameter, it doesn't actually load the file contents until it is first needed.  My issue is, I don't want each OnPaint operation to be delayed by a file read, I want to make sure the data is preloaded before I try to paint the controls, otherwise I get flickering and slow painting.

Is there a good way to force an image to be preloaded?  What are the discrepancies between Image.FromFile, Image.FromStream, new Bitmap(fileName), etc?  Do any of these load all the bytes right away, or is it delayed until they are first needed?

Here's my code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes); // byte[] array
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
ms.Flush();
ms.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI+ which underlies the Image classes require that the source stream remain open while the Image exists to work properly. It's also a bad idea to write changes to the source stream while Image is using it. Changes should be saved to a different stream.

Everything derived from Image uses a Stream under the covers. Their loading behaviors are the same.

Image does not Close or Dispose a stream that was provided to it via FromStream. You have to manage that yourself.

Also, calling Flush on a Stream only has an effect if the Stream has been written to.

If you're looking to improve UI behavior for your PictureBoxes, try this:

1. Set InitialImage to a small spinner GIF.
2. Set WaitOnLoad to false.
3. Specify the image by setting ImageLocation. (You can use a filespec or a URL in it.)
4. Load the images asynchronously using the LoadAsync method.

Answer (score 0):

1)

> If a Bitmap has a dependency on a memory stream or file stream, will
>   it dispose of the source when you dispose of it? Or is this only when
>   it creates the stream itself using Bitmap.FromFile?

Take a look at [Image.FromStream Method (Stream, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4.aspx):

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

2)

> The PictureBox must be caching the image in some way. I've never had
>   an error because I don't need to touch the image once it has been set.

You just should **not dispose the Image instance since it has been assigned to the PictureBox** (i.e. picture box is using it) and **while PictureBox uses it**. Otherwise, PictureBox will try using disposed image and it should lead to some "not good" consequences.

[PictureBox.Image Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx):

> Note If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox
>   controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing
>   the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur.

**Update:**

Sample with practically the same scenario: [HOW TO: Copy a Picture from a Database Directly to a PictureBox Control with Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317701).

Comment: Did you read my results from my testing?  I disposed of the stream used for Image.FromStream and yet my PictureBox controls are still painting fine.  I'm just trying to figure out why this happens, to better understand how to get the best performance from PictureBoxes.

Comment: @Moozhe, I suppose, MemoryStream Dispose() does not actually **dispose** the memory because of MemoryStream implementation: it uses simple byte array (which will be garbage collected). Could you please try the experiment with FileStream class?

Comment: That sounds right since the MemoryStream didn't allocate the memory... the PictureBox must be holding a reference to the memory address of the byte[] array which is why it's not getting garbage collected.

Comment: I just tried with a FileStream.  I created a new temp file and wrote all the bytes to it.  Then disposed of the stream, created a new stream to read from that file, created an Image from that stream and assigned it to the PictureBox, then disposed of the stream again.  Still no errors, the PictureBoxes can still access the image.

Comment: For further testing, I just watched as the .tmp files were created as the images were loaded.  Then I deleted all the .tmp files, and I can still move and repaint the PictureBoxes fine.  So it must be stored in memory somewhere.

Comment: @Moozhe, thank you very much for your experiment. Image just reads the content from the Stream, so the Stream can be safely disposed right after that. But the Image instance (assigned to the PictureBox instance) should not be disposed while PictureBox is using it. I've slightly updated the answer.